# Unable to access CDN endpoint via custom subdomain

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

my team and I are currently exploring using Azure static site blobs and CDN endpoints to host several web apps.

We have successfully deployed our static files to the blog storage and our entire test app loads on both the primary (*name*.*abc*.web.core.windows.net) and CDN (*name*.azureedge.net) endpoints. When it comes to mapping a custom subdomain via the “cdnverify” temporary step, however, I am unsuccessful.

I have very carefully followed and quintuple-checked all steps in the support doc "Tutorial: Add a custom domain to your Azure CDN endpoint" ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain)).

[This is my current DNS config (via Namecheap).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnHDR.png)

When I skip the **cdnverify** step, e.g. assign the azureedge CNAME value directly to a host called “v2”, and add that as a custom domain in my Azure portal CDN blade, the subdomain begins loading the CDN endpoint and can even have a CDN-managed HTTPS cert deployed with no manual verification. A `dig` command to this host (v2.ourdomain.org) finds an expected response [(view here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIQ6q.png).

Here's the rub, though. If I assign a CNAME host of “*cdnverify*.static” to “*cdnverify*.*name*.azureedge.net.” and add it as a custom domain in the portal’s CDN blade, however, this secondary subdomain never loads our endpoint, and cannot deploy an HTTPS cert. The Azure portal verified this host when added to the endpoint and a `dig` command to “*cdnverify*.static.ourdomain.org” shows [this answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbXen.png), which looks good.

A `dig` command to “static.ourdomain.org” returns no answer and a ping command says “unknown host”. This is expected since I’ve not created such a record yet, and so I am wondering how we’re meant to ensure this subdomain is verified as per the “Verify the custom domain” section in the above-mentioned doc.

It’s very important for us that the **cdnverify** host works and can be assigned a certificate before we permanently re-locate our domains as these apps are already in production. At this point, I am at a loss over what to try next. If possible, I’d love to know what step(s) I am missing, or what can further be done to diagnose the issue.

Many thanks to anybody who might have some advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cdnverify` subdomain is to create a **temporary** CNAME mapping to avoid interruption of web traffic. With this method, users can access your domain without interruption while the DNS mapping occurs. If you have not any existing web app work, you can skip the `cdnverify` step.

From your description, "a dig command to `cdnverify.static.ourdomain.org` shows this answer, which looks good." It indicates that the `cdnverify` host works and you have verified that. You just need to [associate the custom domain with your CDN endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain#associate-the-custom-domain-with-your-cdn-endpoint).
In this step, you enter your custom domain like `static.ourdomain.org`, including the subdomain. **Do not use the `cdnverify` subdomain name**.

After you have added the custom domain `static.ourdomain.org` successfully in the CDN endpoint.

> At this point, your custom domain has been verified by Azure, but
>   traffic to your domain is not yet being routed to your CDN endpoint.
>   After waiting long enough to allow the custom domain settings to
>   propagate to the CDN edge nodes (90 minutes for Azure CDN from
>   Verizon, 1-2 minutes for Azure CDN from Akamai), **return to your DNS
>   registrar's web site and create another CNAME record that maps your
>   subdomain to your CDN endpoint.** For example, specify the subdomain as
>   www or cdn, and the hostname as .azureedge.net. With
>   this step, the registration of your custom domain is complete.

After you have completed the registration of your custom domain, [verify that custom domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain#verify-the-custom-domain) references your CDN endpoint.

Finally, you could freely remove the `cdnverify` CNAME record in your domain provider as it was necessary only as an intermediary step..

Ref: https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain.md#how-to-map-custom-domain-to-content-delivery-network-cdn-endpoint

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for you response. I think where I am still getting tripped up is at the stage "Verify the custom domain". In this step, I ought to theoretically be able to access my static web content via the temporary subdomain, e.g. `static.ourdomain.org` as per the docs, but I cannot. Thusly, I can't proceed to the "Map the permanent custom domain" step. Note that I _can_ access content via my `v2` subdomain, for which I bypassed *cdnverify*. Please let me know if there's anything else I can provide to clarify further.

Comment: I think that docs are not clear and lack one step. [Here](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain.md#register-a-custom-domain-for-an-azure-cdn-endpoint-using-the-intermediary-cdnverify-subdomain) are detailed steps. From steps 1-8, your custom domain has been verified by Azure. In the step 9, after you associate the custom domain in CDN endpoint, you need to add another CNAME record that maps your subdomain to your CDN endpoint. After all these steps, the registration of your custom domain is complete.

Comment: After you have completed the registration of your custom domain, you can verify that custom domain references your CDN endpoint. Also edit it in my reply. Let me know if this solves your question.

Comment: Thanks so much for this clearer documentation. So it seems I misunderstood the official docs, which seem to intimate that somehow the intermediate verify subdomain is able to access resources on a CDN, but that seems untrue. I wish the official docs were clearer on this as I spent quite a while trying to clear this up. I hope this thread helps somebody else save some time. Thanks so much!